# Grub is unable to detect Windows

Tags: dual-boot, 13.04, windows-7, uefi

I installed Ubuntu and windows 7 in UEFI mode, but Grub is unable to detect windows.

I ran boot repair, and here are the contents of the [boot info file](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/5797776/)

Comment: What is output from: **`sudo update-grub`** ?

Comment: your Boot-Info is incomplete. Please indicate the URL provided by Boot-Repair's Recommended Repair.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed several peculiarities in your Boot Info Script output:

- The Boot Info Script output indicates that the Windows boot loader is installed in the MBR of the disk; but this is normally only the case for BIOS-mode installs of Windows, which also necessarily use MBR rather than GPT. Your disk, though, uses GPT.
- The disk seems to have an ESP (`/dev/sda2`), but that ESP contains no EFI-mode Windows boot loader -- or at least, the Boot Info Script hasn't identified one.
- Your Windows `C:` partition seems to be `/dev/sda1`, whereas your ESP is `/dev/sda2`. This is legal, but unusual. It indicates manual partitioning of some sort rather than a stock installation as done by the Windows installer or by an OEM setup.

Based on this evidence, my hypothesis is that you took a BIOS-mode Windows installation, converted the disk to GPT, and installed Linux. If I'm right, then this explains all the peculiarities I've identified, and it also explains why Windows won't boot: It's configured for BIOS-mode booting, which is now impossible, and it lacks an EFI-mode boot loader. The good news is that you can fix these problems. The bad news is that it will be a bit of a pain to do so.

You can consult [this page](https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI) for instructions on converting Windows to boot in EFI mode. Note, however, that those instructions include a lot of steps related to installing the DUET package, which you don't need if your firmware is based on EFI. (DUET is a software-loaded EFI for BIOS-based computers.) Basically, you need to pay attention to steps 3.5 through 3.7 on that page.

Alternatively, you can wipe the disk clean and re-install both Windows and Linux. This is likely to be the easier way to proceed, but you'll lose any OS customizations you may have created.